# Attribute Based Access Controll issue for AWS Lambda with IAM policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to follow [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_attribute-based-access-control.html) for Secret Manager and tried applying attribute based access controll (ABAC) for AWS Lambda by using this user role policy linkage:

1. Create IAM user
2. Assign a role to this IAM user
3. Role is assigned an ABAC policy for lambda.

currently my ABAC policy for Lambda usage for different users in a project is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaPolicyForProject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "lambda:Get*",
                "lambda:List*",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:ListStateMachines",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "xray:GetTraceSummaries",
                "xray:BatchGetTraces"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/accessproject": "${aws:PrincipalTag/accessproject}",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/accessteam": "${aws:PrincipalTag/accessteam}",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/costcenter": "${aws:PrincipalTag/costcenter}"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This does not work for a user when the `costcenter`, `accessteam`, `accessproject` tags are similar for both IAM user and lambda.

However, it works when I remove the condition in the above policy (this shows IAM is able to access lambda policy).

Can I know what I am missing from the tutorial above? I did cross check all tags for lambda, policies and IAM users, and they are same as per the docs.

Comment: What do you mean by the `costcenter`, `accessteam`, `accessproject` tags are similar for IAM user and lambda? Similar or the same?

Comment: is it still unclear what to do?

Comment: No, thanks for your previse answer, I get it now, "Some Secrets Manager actions don't support that resource type" makes sense.

Comment: `costcenter`, `accessteam`, `accessproject` are same as IAM user and lambda tags

Comment: Glad to hear. If it's clear feel free to upvote or mark as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to be in the `Actions` you defined. According to the tutorial you followed:

> [...] see [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssecretsmanager.html) for AWS Secrets Manager. That page shows that actions performed on the [**Secret** resource type](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_awssecretsmanager.html#awssecretsmanager-resources-for-iam-policies) support the `secretsmanager:ResourceTag/tag-key` condition key. Some Secrets Manager actions don't support that resource type, including `GetRandomPassword` and `ListSecrets`.

Have a look at [actions, resources, and condition keys for AWS services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/reference_policies_actions-resources-contextkeys.html) and for each service make sure the action supports the `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}` condition. I didn't go through all the permissions but already the CloudWatch actions `GetMetricData` and `ListMetrics` do not support the `aws:ResourceTag/${TagKey}` condition. Same goes for `ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups`,
`ec2:DescribeSubnets`, `ec2:DescribeVpcs`, and probably a few more.

You must create additional statements to allow those actions i.e:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "LambdaPolicyForProject",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:ListStackResources",
                "kms:ListAliases",
                "iam:GetPolicy",
                "iam:GetPolicyVersion",
                "iam:GetRole",
                "iam:GetRolePolicy",
                "iam:ListAttachedRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRolePolicies",
                "iam:ListRoles",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "lambda:Get*",
                "lambda:List*",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:ListStateMachines",
                "tag:GetResources",
                "xray:GetTraceSummaries",
                "xray:BatchGetTraces"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:ResourceTag/accessproject": "${aws:PrincipalTag/accessproject}",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/accessteam": "${aws:PrincipalTag/accessteam}",
                    "aws:ResourceTag/costcenter": "${aws:PrincipalTag/costcenter}"
                }
            }
        },{
            "Sid": "LambdaPolicyForProjectNoTags",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:GetMetricData",
                "cloudwatch:ListMetrics",
                "ec2:DescribeSecurityGroups",
                "ec2:DescribeSubnets",
                "ec2:DescribeVpcs"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Once you have a working policy, please familiarize yourself with the [IAM best practices](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/best-practices.html#grant-least-privilege) as the use of wildcard resouce access should be avoided whenever possible (principle of granting least privilege).